# Implementing the Ajax.org ACE editor in IE9

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

The [ACE kitchen sink demo](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html) works in IE9, but not in an out-of-the-box implementation.  From what I can tell in the [kitchen sink code](http://ace.ajax.org/build/demo/kitchen-sink/kitchen-sink-uncompressed.js), there seems to be a reasonable amount of effort that occurs outside of the library to get the editor working in IE9.

So the question is, what's the bare minimum code to achieve a working ACE editor in IE9?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Not in IE. For production-level use, I use CodeMirror 2 now: http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit misleading.
Kitchen sink demo [code](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/demo/kitchen-sink) never had any IE specific stuff, the file linked in the question was a built file with all ace code.

The most likely causes of ace not working in ie9 is document being loaded in quirks mode or ie8 mode.

Comment: When this question was asked nearly two years ago, Ace was not IE-ready out of the box. I remember a separate module that was present in the kitchen sink demo, but not documented. Others had the same issue. Now that Ace has evolved, the question has become moot.